# Primary Local DC in Cassandra

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Which one is the primary local datacenter in cassandra as mentioned in the description of "cass_cluster_set_load_balance_dc_aware" in https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/api/struct.CassCluster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set it as 2nd parameter (`local_dc`) of the `cass_cluster_set_load_balance_dc_aware` function.  You need to specify correct DC name from your cluster.

```
CassError cass_cluster_set_load_balance_dc_aware(CassCluster* cluster,
              const char* local_dc,
              unsigned used_hosts_per_remote_dc,
              cass_bool_t allow_remote_dcs_for_local_cl);
```